# Trying to get property 'image' of non-object

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

In Controller

```
public function index()
{
    $profile = Profile::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->first();
    return view('profile', compact('profile'));
}
```

In Blade View

```
 <div class="card mb-5">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ asset('images/'.$profile->image ? $profile->image : "" ) }}"
        alt="Profile User">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">{{Auth::user() ? Auth::user()->name :""}}</h5>
        <p class="card-text">{{Auth::user() ?Auth::user()->email :""}}.</p>
      </div>
      <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
        <li class="list-group-item">{{$profile ? $profile->gender :"Belum Di isi"}}</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">{{$profile ? $profile->phone :"Belum Di isi"}}</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">{{$profile ? $profile->address :"Belum Di isi"}}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

But above code throw an error Trying to get property of non-object.
How can you fix these errors, so that the image runs again without an error

Comment: show the dd() of $profile, add dd($profile) in your controller . Does it gives the same error?

Comment: when dd ($ profile) the result is null

Comment: It is showing that error because your $profile object is null. You should check it first before access its property. You should try this `$profile ? $profile->image : ""`

Comment: I think the data not exist that's why you get this error. If so, then change `first()` to `firstOrFail` it will throw an 404 error if no data exist. `$profile = Profile::where('user_id', auth()->user()-id)->firstOrFail();`

Comment: I've tried it but still error

Comment: @Dinar I gave you an answer, try this

Answer (score 1):

In my case! every time this error happens in my code this is because `$item->image` is not present in my collection instance.

Answer (score 0):

The error is thrown because your `$profile` variable is not an object, it can be an `array` or `null`. Try `dd($profile)` to make sure that you are passing an object

if you are passing an object then try changing your code like this if you are passing an object

```
  <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ asset('images/' . $profile ? $profile->image : "" )}}"/>
```

or like below if you are passing an array

```
 <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ asset('images/' . isset($profile['image'] ? $profile['image'] : "" )}}"/>
```

Comment: when i use the isset property an error like this occurs = Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead)

Answer (score 0):

Do a Auth check before use the auth. 
Use `firstOrFail` instead of `first`,  it will throw a 404 error if get null value :

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

public function index()
{
    if (Auth::check())
    {
        $profile = Profile::where('user_id', Auth::id())->firstOrFail();
        return view('profile', compact('profile'));
     } else {
        return "You are not logged in";
    }
}
```